# Multiple clones of model spawning in target (Vuforia and Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am trying to place a sphere on a ground plane and on a button click remove the sphere and place a cube.

This is the [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APr1W.png) attached to the AR camera object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using System.Collections;
public class ModelSwapper : MonoBehaviour {
    public AnchorStageBehaviour theTrackable;
    public Transform myModelPrefab;
    private bool mSwapModel = false;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Transform myModelTrf = GameObject.Instantiate(myModelPrefab) as Transform;
        myModelTrf.parent = theTrackable.transform;
        myModelTrf.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
        myModelTrf.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        myModelTrf.localScale = new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
        myModelTrf.gameObject.active = true;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (mSwapModel && theTrackable != null) {
            SwapModel();
            mSwapModel = false;
        }
    }
    void OnGUI() {
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect(50,50,120,40), "Swap Model")) {
            mSwapModel = true;
        }
    }
    private void SwapModel() {
        GameObject trackableGameObject = theTrackable.gameObject;
        //disable any pre-existing augmentation
        for (int i = 0; i < trackableGameObject.transform.GetChildCount(); i++)
        {
            Transform child = trackableGameObject.transform.GetChild(i);
            child.gameObject.active = false;
        }

        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        // Re-parent the cube as child of the trackable gameObject
        cube.transform.parent = theTrackable.transform;
        // Adjust the position and scale
        // so that it fits nicely on the target
        cube.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0.2f, 0);
        cube.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
        // Make sure it is active
        cube.active = true;
    }
}
```

But instead, it spawns multiple cubes along with the sphere. 
[Multiple clones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJFPM.png)

Since, there isn't much documentation or anything else on Vuforia ground plane, it's hard to get things done. Why is this behaving strange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the `Update` and it should fix your issue, replace these two methods in your script with the following:

```
void Update () {

        }
void OnGUI() {
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect(50,50,120,40), "Swap Model")) {
        if(theTrackable)
        {
            SwapModel();
        }

    }
}
```